# How to start mining Ethereum

Tags: mining, wallets

First I'm sorry for the inconvenience, and I'm sorry for this question (If it violates the laws of society) but I have a curiosity to start mining Ethereum.

I start with https://ethereum.org/ to know about it, but unfortunately without any result.

Can you please share with me the official application to start mining Ethereum? and all positive and negative information about Ethereum? and where I can create my wallet?

Comment: Try starting from here - https://geth.ethereum.org/

Comment: HI! This question is a bit out of the range of a question for this site, I'd recommend looking for a good subreddit, maybe [/r/EtherMining](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/). I think you'll find it better suited for getting the information you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mine Ethereum using geth

Install geth on your pc then create an account using "geth account new" , then simply just run geth with --mine option then it will start mining the ether and all the earned ether will be sent to the account generated

Note:- As the ether mainnet is using POW you require a very powerful pc high best graphic card

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, so we can say that the account equal the wallet ?

Comment: yes but using wallet like metamask makes it more secure

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have last question if you want. when I use `geth --mine` Will the currencies be added directly to the wallet?

Comment: PS: I created the wallet in metamask and I added using private key

Comment: Yes and if you want to add your metamask address in geth then you can use geth --help to get the appropriate command to do so